# Asterisk IVRS setting

Tags: asterisk

I'm using asterisk 13.9.1 right now and I wanna set an IVRS : when the user dial to a extension, say 512, the system will play a .wav file asking for user input his/her credit card number, which is 16 digit, after the user input 16 digit , the system will read the digit out and ask to confirm(an .wav again), then the user should input either 1 (confirm) or 0 (back to input), if the input is 1, then the system forward the call to another extension(someone in charge).
 I've written the code for asking input, but it doesn't work and I dont know how to fix it, the system can only play the .wav asking for input now and cant listen for user input, here is my extensions.conf

```
    [voicemenu-custom-200] ; once the user dial 512, the following section 

    include default        ; will be executed
    exten = s,1,NoOp(InCallExt)
    exten = s,2,Answer()
    exten = s,3,Playback(dir-intro); I'm using the default sound right now, 
    ; here is where the system ask for user input
    exten => s,1,Gotoif($[ "${LEN(${extensao})}" < "16"]?16:100)
    ; here might be listening the 16 digit input

    exten => s,n,Read(digito||16)
    exten => s,n,SayDigits(${digito})
    exten => s,n,Set(extensao=${extensao}${digito})
    exten => h,1,hangup()
```

I havent do the confirmation part yet since the system cant read out the digit, 
the code is not created by me to be honest, I just google it and give it some modification, I dont know where does the digit is saved and read from which file.
I tail the log messages after dialing 512 (the extension)
there is error saying: app_voicemail.c: Couldn't find mailbox 801 in context default
Note that 801 is the user I'm currently logging in

Answer (score 0):

You have write dialplan for extension 512. Dialplan you have shown is for empty extension(s).

For more info better read some nice book like  ORelly "Asterisk the future of telephony", too much issues in your task still have be solved.